# Decode HMAC signature

Tags: ruby, algorithm, api, signature, hmac

I decode (secret_key,client_id, path) into signature by following code :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'base64'
require 'cgi'
require 'hmac-sha1'
@client_id = "asdkasdlda"
@secret = "3fdsdsfxds"

binary_key = Base64.decode64(@secret)

params.update({"client" => @client_id})
path = uri_path + "?" + params.collect{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.inject{|initial,cur| initial + "&" + cur}

digest = HMAC::SHA1.new(binary_key).update(path).digest
digest = Base64.encode64(digest).gsub(/[+\/]/, {"+" => "-", "/" => "_"}).delete("=")
return "#{path}&sig=#{digest}"
```

So, this code generates `sig` and `path`. we send request to server in following way:

```
/api/v1/customers/sign_in.json?user[email]=amit1656789@gmail.com&user[password]=[FILTERED]&client=asdkasdlda&sig=JSdP5xUHhgS8ZbKApBOIlsJKg_Q
```

Now, on server side, i want to decode this params["sign"] into app_id, secret_key and path means reverse process of above code. But i am not found any reverse process of this. Means

```
(app_id, secret, path) =>  "signature"
"signature"      =>   (app_id, secret, path) /* Here i stuck */
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decode" here? Your encode is just Base64 with some web-safe substitutions (BTW see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64 ) - I presume you don't just want the reverse of that, but the rest of your sample doesn't "encode" anything. Perhaps an example input, "encoded value" and output you expect would help

Comment: Output is "true" or "false", because it is not possible to "decode" MAC, you can only verify it. Verification code is basically two last lines of code in question, and a final check whether the calculated MAC value is the same as required.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Actually i want to encode (secret_key,app_id, path) this as a client side and send signature to server side and at server side, i want to decode that signature into secret_key, app_id, path. On, server side, i verify that secret key, app_id and path. Please answer this.

Comment: @AmitSuroliya: I don't think that has made your question clearer. In fact it is worse. For a start, you don't have any variable called `app_id` - what is it? Please give sample data. Maybe run the code above with input that you want to test, show what the value is, and explain how you wnat to process that, and what the expected results should be . . . use Ruby *code* to explain what you need, not the English description. It is easier to be precise.

Comment: Hi thanks @NeilSlater for support my question, I update sample client_id(app_id) and secret. Please now help me around. Thanks a lot....!!!

Comment: @AmitSuroliya: I am sorry I am trying to understand your question, but I cannot. I think you may not understand what an HMAC is. I could help you there, but I need to see some code. Please add code for your server side. Put question marks on code where you are not sure what to do. Put comments with expected values from an example. For instance, if `@secret="3fdsdsfxds"`, `@client_id="asdkasdlda"`, `path='/hello.txt'`, what would you send from client to server, and what do you expect server to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for reply @NeilSlater, i update question. Please check question one more time. Thanks....!!!

Answer (score 3):

First thing you should know:

> "signature" => (app_id, secret, path)

This is *not possible*. It is not how MACs of any kind work. The signature does not contain the data. Signatures are meant to be sent *alongside* the message that they sign.

For secure HMAC, you should *never* send the secret with the message that you sign. It is also not possible to figure out a secret from the signature, except by repeatedly guessing what the value might be.

---

The usual way to confirm a signature is to follow the same process on the server, signing the same message, using the same secret (which the server should *already* have), and compare the signatures. You have made it difficult for yourself because you have signed the params as you sent them, and then put the signature on the end. You have to re-construct the message.

First, you need to use whatever web server library you can to get the request URI including the query string

```
signed_uri = "/api/v1/customers/sign_in.json?user[email]=amit1656789@gmail.com&user[password]=[FILTERED]&client=asdkasdlda&sig=JSdP5xUHhgS8ZbKApBOIlsJKg_Q"
```

Then split it into the message and its signature (I'll leave that to you, but just a regular expression ought to work):

```
message = "/api/v1/customers/sign_in.json?user[email]=amit1656789@gmail.com&user[password]=[FILTERED]&client=asdkasdlda"

signature = "JSdP5xUHhgS8ZbKApBOIlsJKg_Q"
```

To decode this signature back to the original digest (for easy comparison), just reverse the replace and encoding you did at the end on the client:

```
client_digest = Base64.decode64( 
  signature.gsub(/[-_]/, {"-" => "+", "_" => "/"}) )
```

Then on the server (where you should already have a value for @secret), calculate what you *expect* the signature to be:

```
@secret = '3fdsdsfxds'
binary_key = Base64.decode64(@secret)

server_digest = HMAC::SHA1.new(binary_key).update( message ).digest

if server_digest == client_digest
  puts "The message was signed correctly"
else
  puts "ERROR: The message or signature is not correct!"
end
```